# Table of contents change font of numbers

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents

I want to change the font of the numbers in the ToC.

How do I do this?

I am using font A for the words
and
I am using font B for the page numbers. I want to use font B for the numbers in the table of contents as well. Is that possible?

EDIT: An example of a page of my booklet:

[image]

I want the text font in the table of contents, but the numbers in the table of contents should be like the font of the number in the example.

EDIT 2: The code so far:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex

% Memoir options
\documentclass[12pt,
  openany,
  twoside,
  a5paper
  ]{memoir}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\color{blue!50!green!80!black}\large}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\defpagestyle{nocf}{
    {}
    {}
    {}
  }
  {{}{}{}
}


% Page size
\setlength{\headheight}{18.0pt}
\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

% Indent
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\nonzeroparskip

% Graphics
\usepackage[dvipnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xfp}

% Ornament
\PassOptionsToPackage{object=vectorian}{pgfornament}
\usepackage{myornament}

% Language settings
\usepackage[german,
  main=german]{babel}

% Text generator
\usepackage{blindtext}

% Font settings
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{srd.otf}[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]

%inhoudsopgave

\renewcommand{\cftsectionformatpnum}{<font for chapters page numbers>}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\color{red}\sffamily\large}% change page numbers font <<<<<<<<<< 
\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{\thepage}%


\renewcommand{\cftsectionformatpnum}{\color{red}\sffamily}% change sections page numbers font <<<<<<<<<

% Secties
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand*{\justifyheading}{\raggedleft}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{12}\bfseries\justifyheading}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{} % suppress page number <<<<<
\Bordertrue

\begin{center}

    {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont Die neunundneunzig schönen Gesetze}
    {\fontsize{38}{38}\selectfont Rastullahs}

   \vspace{\fill
    \includegraphics{tent.jpg} 
  \vspace{\fill} \\
    \fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont und einige Bemerkungen \\
    zum Bekenntnis und Gebet \\
und zur Zeitrechnung}

\end{center}

\newpage

\begin{flushright}

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\color{black}\sffamily\large}% change font <<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{\thepage}% show page numebering <<<<<<<<<<<

\section*{Zum Kalender}
\vspace{8pt}

Das erste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige zählt getreulich die Tage, damit er gewiss die sieben vom achten und neunten zu trennen versteht. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das zweite Gesetz  \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige schafft mit Fleiß an jedem der sieben Tage. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das dritte Gesetz  \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige erinnert sich des großen Frevels am achten Tag. Zorn und Trauer erfüllen ihn ganz und hindern ihn an Arbeit und Essen. Der Gottgefällige nimmt nur Wasser, auch Wein - aber nur in Maßen - zu sich und übt sich in Enthaltsamkeit. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das vierte Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

 Der Gottgefällige erinnert sich der großen Freude am neunten Tag. Er feiert ihn voll stiller Zufriedenheit. \\
\vspace{\fill}
\newpage

Das achte Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige hemmt nach wiederum acht mal neun Tagen nicht seinen Zorn auf alle Ungläubigen oder diejenigen, die seine Ehre verletzen oder Ihm freveln. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das neunte Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige ruht nach den nächsten acht mal neun Tagen von Sonnenaufgang bis Sonnenuntergang und preist in der Stille und Ruhe Seine Gnade und Weisheit. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das zehnte Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige feiert nach weiteren acht mal neun Tagen, am Ende des Jahres, zu Seinen Ehren und erfreut sich an all dem Schönen in der Welt, die Er erschaffen hat. \\
\vspace{\fill}
\newpage

\section*{Zur Rastullahs schönen Schöpfung}
\vspace{8pt}

Das elfte Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige lässt Seiner \\ Schöpfung den nötigen Respekt zuteilwerden. \\
\vspace{8pt}

das zwölfte Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige hütet in Seinem Namen die gesamte Schöpfung, auf dass sie niemand zerstöre oder in ihrer Schönheit beeinträchtige. \\
\vspace{8pt}

das dreizehnte Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige darf sich durch Seine Schöpfung nähren, jedoch nur mit Bedacht. \\
\vspace{\fill}
\newpage

\section*{Zu den Speisengeboten}
\vspace{8pt}

Das vierzehnte Gesetz \\
 \vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige speist nichts, was mehr als sechs Beine hat. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das fünfzehnte Gesetz \\
 \vspace{8pt}

 Der Gottgefällige speist nichts, was vier, fünf oder sechs Beine und auch Flügel hat. \\
 \vspace{8pt}

Das sechszehnte Gesetz \\
 \vspace{8pt}

 Der Gottgefällige speist nichts, was lange Ohren und eine Schuppenhaut hat und im Wasser lebt. \\
 \vspace{8pt}

Das siebzehnte Gesetz \\
 \vspace{8pt}

 Der Gottgefällige speist keine Nebelkrähe und keine Sandkrähe, auch die Rohrdommel nicht, den Lämmergeier und den Bartgeier, die Fledermaus und den Sturzpelikan. \\
 \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

Das achtzehnte Gesetz \\ 
 \vspace{8pt}

 Der Gottgefällige speist keine gefiederten Wesen, die gespaltene Hufe haben. \\
 \vspace{8pt}

Das neunzehnte Gesetz \\
 \vspace{8pt}

 Der Gottgefällige speist nicht vom eigenen Pferd, Kamel oder Maultier und nicht vom Pferd oder einem anderen Reittier des Freundes oder Vaters. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das zwanzigste Gesetz \\
 \vspace{8pt}

 Der Gottgefällige speist nicht vom Maulwurf, auch nicht von der gelbpelzigen Art, die im Khoramgebirge haust. \\
 \vspace{8pt}
 
Das einundzwanzigste Gesetz \\
 \vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige speist nicht, wenn er keinen Hunger oder Durst verspürt, denn die Schöpfung ist Ihm lieb. \\
 \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

Das zweiundzwanzigste Gesetz \\
 \vspace{8pt}

 Der Gottgefällige speist und trinkt ohne Eile und stets regelmäßig. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das dreiundzwanzigste Gesetz \\
 \vspace{8pt}

 Der Gottgefällige speist nichts, was ein Ungläubiger berührt, gekocht, geschlachtet oder gar angefertigt hat. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das vierundzwanzigste Gesetz \\
 \vspace{8pt}

 Der Gottgefällige speist nicht vom Geschirr, das von Ungläubigen berührt wurde.\\
 \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

\section*{Zum Verhalten des Rechtgläubigen}
\vspace{8pt}

Das fünfundzwanzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige wählt stets den Weg, der Ihm Wohlgefallen bereitet. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das sechsundzwanzigste Gesetz  \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige wählt stets das Wort, das Ihm Wohlgefallen bereitet.  \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das siebenundzwanzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

 Der Gottgefällige zügelt seine Neugierde, wenn eine Gefahr offensichtlich ist. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das achtundzwanzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige ist sich stets der gefährlichen Versuchung durch Götzen und Dämonen bewusst. \\
 \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

Das neunundzwanzigste Gesetz  \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige kriecht nicht vor Angst im Sand, wenn ihm Widernatürliches und Unbekanntes widerfährt. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das dreißigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

 Der Gottgefällige erahnt durch Seine Gunst im Voraus, was ihm an Gefahren widerfährt.\\
\vspace{8pt}

Das einunddreißigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige meidet es, von bösen Dingen zu sprechen. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das zweiunddreißigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige fühlt Seinen nahen Hauch im schnellen und wendigen Kampf und lässt sich von Seiner Hand führen. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das dreiunddreißigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige folgt den Eingebungen, die Er ihm zu jeder Zeit zukommen lässt. \\
 \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

Das vierunddreißigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige gibt diese Eingebungen an seine Brüder und Kampfgefährten weiter, auf dass auch sie Sein Wort vernehmen. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das fünfunddreißigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige prüft jeden Gedanken auf den Einfluss alles Schändlichen. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das sechsunddreißigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige befleißigt sich der Sanftmut an allen neun Tagen in allen Gottesnamen im Jahreslauf. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das siebenunddreißigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige behandelt sein Pferd, seine Frauen und Töchter gut, so sie ihm treu und ergeben sind. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das achtunddreißigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige ehrt und liebt seine Sippe und seine Kampfgefährten. \\
 \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

Das neununddreißigste Gesetz \\
Der Gottgefällige lässt seine Freunde und Kampfgefährten nie im Stich, auf dass er sich auch ihrer Hilfe in der Not versichern kann. Er ist ihnen im Kampf um ihre Ehre dienlich, denn ihre Ehre ist auch die seine. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das vierzigste Gesetz \\
 Der Gottgefällige steht seinen Kampfgefährten und seiner Sippe auch dann treu zur Seite, wenn sein Leben gefährdet ist. \\
 \vspace{8pt}
 
Das einundvierzigste Gesetz \\
Der Gottgefällige hemmt niemals seinen Zorn, wenn seine Ehre verletzt, gekränkt oder gar in Frage gestellt wurde. \\
 \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

Das zweiundvierzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

 Der Gottgefällige lässt seinem Zorn freie Bahn, wenn die Ehre eines Freundes, seines Vaters, seines Sohnes, seines Pferdes oder seiner Frau oder Tochter, verletzt, gekränkt oder in Frage gestellt wurde. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das dreiundvierzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

 Der Gottgefällige hemmt niemals seinen Zorn, wenn große Rachetaten zu vollführen sind an denen, die versuchen seine Brüder zu vergiften oder zu vernichten und mit Grimm wird er sie strafen. \\
 \vspace{8pt}

Das vierundvierzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige zügelt seinen Zorn, wenn die gerechte Rache geübt worden ist. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das fünfundvierzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige zügelt seinen Zorn, wenn der Rat der Älteren seine Ehre als wiederhergestellt ansieht. \\
 \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

Das sechsundvierzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige zügelt seinen Zorn, wenn sein Feind zu ihm herantritt, um die gerechte Strafe auf sich zu nehmen. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das siebenundvierzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige legt Zeugnis ab vor den Älteren, dass seine Ehre wiederhergestellt wurde und ist sich bewusst, dass erst dann auch vor Ihm seine Ehre vollkommen ist. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das achtundvierzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige wird für Ihn auch seinen wertvollsten Besitz opfern, so dies nötig ist. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das neunundvierzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige wird nie seinen Glauben oder seine Ehre opfern.\\
 \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

\section*{Zur Mehrung von Rastullahs Macht und Ruhm}
\vspace{8pt}

Das fünfzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige trachtet stets danach, Seinen Ruhm zu mehren. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das einundfünfzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige trachtet stets danach, Seine Macht auszudehnen. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das zweiundfünfzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige trachtet stets danach, in allem Seine Herrlichkeit zu erkennen. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das dreiundfünfzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige trachtet stets danach, auch andere Seine Herrlichkeit erkennen zu lassen. \\
 \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

Das vierundfünfzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige trachtet stets danach, dass Sein Ruhm und Seine Herrlichkeit nicht eingeschränkt oder in Frage gestellt werden. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das fünfundfünfzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige trachtet stets danach, dass Seine Gesetze nicht in Vergessenheit geraten oder in ihrem Sinn verändert werden.\\
 \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

\section*{Zu den Glaubensgeboten}
\vspace{8pt}

Das sechsundfünfzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

 Der Gottgefällige weiß, dass er in höherer Achtung bei Ihm steht als die Ungläubigen. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das siebenundfünfzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige weiß, dass er sich trotzdem im Kampf gegen die Ungläubigen bewähren und beweisen muss. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das achtundfünfzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige dankt Ihm für jede Möglichkeit, seinen Mut und seinen Glauben zu beweisen. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das neunundfünfzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

 Der Gottgefällige schreckt nie davor zurück, seinen Mut und seinen Glauben vor Ihm zu beweisen. \\
 \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

Das sechszigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

 Der Gottgefällige prüft stets seinen eigenen Glauben, um ihn nie schwach werden zu lassen. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das einundsechzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige lässt seinen Glauben von seiner Sippe und seinen Kampfgefährten überprüfen, auf dass sie ihn stets zu Gottgefälligkeit ermahnen.\\
 \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

\section*{Zum Verhalten gegenüber Ungläubigen}
\vspace{8pt}

Das zweiundsechzigste Gesetz\\
\vspace{8pt}

 Der Gottgefällige meidet die Frauen und wechselt mit ihnen weder Worte noch Blicke - sofern sie nicht in den Ehebund mit ihm getreten sind. \\
 \vspace{8pt}

Das dreiundsechzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige meidet die Ungläubigen und wechselt mit ihnen weder Worte noch Blicke. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das vierundsechzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige meidet die Prediger der falschen Götzen und lässt sich nicht von ihren falschen Zungen verführen. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das fünfundsechzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige wandert mit äußerster Vorsicht durch das Land der Ungläubigen und versichert sich stets Seiner Obhut. \\
 \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

Das sechsundsechzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige sieht mit Abscheu auf die Götzen der Echsen herab und trachtet stets danach, ihren schändlichen Einfluss zu mindern.  \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das siebenundsechzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige meidet die Anhänger der Gott-Echse und wechselt mit ihnen weder Worte noch Blicke. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das achtundsechzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige meidet die Frauen, welche die Gott-Echse verehren, sie sind ihm ein besonderer Gräuel.  \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das neunundsechzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige meidet alle Geister, die dem Bösen dienen und er bekämpft sie mit schierem Glauben. \\
 \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

Das siebzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige meidet ebenso alles Dämonische und hört nicht auf dessen Einflüsterungen, die nur Lästerliches verkünden. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das einundsiebzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige lässt die Ungläubigen im Kampf Seine Macht und Seine Kraft erkennen. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das zweiundsiebzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige lässt ab von den Ungläubigen, so diese Seine Herrlichkeit und Kraft in vollem Ausmaß erkannt haben. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das dreiundsiebzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

 Der Gottgefällige bekämpft jeden umso erbitterter, der vom rechten Glauben abgekommen ist. \\
 \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

Das vierundsiebzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige ist stets auf der Hut vor Verrätern, Heuchlern und Häretikern. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das fünfundsiebzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige prüft den Glauben eines jeden Fremden, bevor er diesen in seinem Zelt aufnimmt.  \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das siebenundsiebzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige urteilt nach dem Glauben eines Fremden und lässt sich nicht vom Äußeren verwirren. \\
 \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

\section*{Zur körperlichen und geistigen Ertüchtigung}
\vspace{8pt}

Das siebenundsiebzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige stärkt Geist und Körper durch Gebet und Kampf. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das achtundsiebzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige macht seinen Geist stark im Glauben. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das neunundsiebzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige macht seinen Körper stark im Kampf für den Glauben. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das achtzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige übt auch den Kampf ohne Waffen und lässt dabei seinen Körper zur Waffe werden.  \\
 \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

Das einundachtzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige wendet im Kampf ohne Waffen nur die drei mal neun Ihm gefälligen Griffe an und versucht nicht mit unlauteren Mitteln, den Sieg an sich zu reißen. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das zweiundachtzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Göttergefällige besudelt weder den Gegner noch den Kampfplatz mit seinem Speichel, denn dieses ist Ihm widerwärtig und soll ihm ein Gräuel sein. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das dreiundachtzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige misst sich mit seinen Kampfgefährten, versucht aber nie, diese zu töten.  \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das vierundachtzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige sucht auch beim Kampf im Gebet Seine Nähe. \\
 \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

Das fünfundachtzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige weiß, dass er Ihn nie in Seiner Gesamtheit erfassen, geschweige denn begreifen kann. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das sechsundachtzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige bittet Ihn um Vergebung, wenn er gesündigt hat und versucht, Ihm bei seiner Buße nahe zu sein.  \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das siebenundachtzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige ist nicht würdig, auch nur ein Haar von Rastullahs Leib anzubeten. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das achtundachtzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige pflegt auch das Gebet unter Anleitung eines Älteren oder eines Seiner innigsten Diener. \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das neunundachtzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige pflegt das Gebet, wenn sich die Sonnenscheibe erhebt und wenn sie sich unter die Welt senkt.  \\
\vspace{8pt}

Das neunzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

 Der Gottgefällige pflegt das Gebet beim höchsten Stand der Sonne und bevor er sich zur Nachtruhe begibt.  \\
 \vspace{8pt}

Das einundneunzigste Gesetz \\
\vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige sieht Ihm beim Gebet direkt ins Angesicht und offenbart Ihm dabei stets seinen ganzen Geist. \\
 \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

\section*{Zur Meidung von Magie}
 \vspace{8pt}

Das zweiundneunzigste Gesetz \\
 \vspace{8pt}

Der Gottgefällige meidet schändliche Magie und Zauberei, denn sie ist Ihm zuwider.  \\
 \vspace{8pt}

Das dreiundneunzigste Gesetz \\
 \vspace{8pt}
 
Der Gottgefällige meidet jeden Vertreter der schändlichen Zauberkunst, denn sie handeln Seinen Gesetzen zuwider. \\
 \vspace{8pt}

\section*{Zur Bestattung}
 \vspace{8pt}

Das vierundneunzigste Gesetz \\
 \vspace{8pt}
 
Der Gottgefällige lässt gläubigen Gefallenen die nötige Ehre zuteilwerden. \\
 \vspace{8pt}

Das fünfundneunzigste Gesetz \\
 \vspace{8pt}
 
 Der Gottgefällige sorgt dafür, dass Gefallene in Seiner Schöpfung aufgehen können.\\
  \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

\section*{Zu den Kleidungsvorschriften}
 \vspace{8pt}

Das sechsundneunzigste Gesetz \\
 \vspace{8pt}
 
Der Gottgefällige kleidet sich in weite und luftige Gewänder. \\
 \vspace{8pt}

Das siebenundneunzigste Gesetz \\
 \vspace{8pt}
 
Der Gottgefällige achtet darauf, dass sein Gewand ihn vor Wind und Sand schützt. \\
 \vspace{8pt}

Das achtundneunzigste Gesetz \\
 \vspace{8pt}
 
Der Gottgefällige lässt seinen Geist und seinen Körper nicht durch die Last einer schweren Rüstung verkommen. \\
 \vspace{8pt}

\section*{Zu den neunundneunzig Gesetzen}
 \vspace{8pt}
 
Das neunundneunzigste Gesetz \\
 \vspace{8pt}
 
Der Gottgefällige bemüht sich stets, ein jedes der neunundneunzig Gesetze ständig im Geiste zu haben.\\
  \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

\section*{Zum Bekenntnis und Gebet }
 \vspace{8pt}

Rastullah ist groß. \\
Rastullah ist groß. \\
Ich bezeuge, 
es gibt keine Gottheit außer Rastullah. \\
Ich bezeuge, der Kalif wurde uns von Rastullah gegeben. \\
Eilt zum Gebet. \\
Eilt zur Seligkeit. \\
Das Gebet ist besser \\ als der Schlaf. \\
Rastullah ist groß. \\
Ich bezeuge, es gibt keine Gottheit außer Rastullah. \\
  \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 


\section*{Zur Zeitrechnung}

Eine Woche zählt neun Nächte. \\
 \vspace{8pt}

Erste Nacht - Laila-al-Kira \\
Nacht des Sieges \\
 \vspace{8pt}

Zweite Nacht - Laila-al-Kadir \\
Nacht der Rechtsprechung \\
 \vspace{8pt}
 
Dritte Nacht  - Laila-al-Iqbal   \\
Nacht des Glückes \\
 \vspace{8pt}
 
Vierte Nacht - Laila-ar-Ra'ad \\
Nacht des Donners \\
 \vspace{8pt}
 
Fünfte Nacht  -  Laila-ar-Rashid \\
Nacht der Weisheit \\
 \vspace{8pt}
 
Sechste Nacht -  Laila-ash-Sharisa \\
Nacht des Tanzes \\
 \vspace{8pt}
 
Siebte Nacht -  Laila-al-Mhânash \\
 Nacht des Altehrwürdigen \\
  \vspace{8pt}
  
Achte Nacht -  Laila-as-Sefra'iz \\
 Nacht des Frevels \\
  \vspace{8pt}
  
Neunte Nacht - 
 Laila-al-Hafla \\
 Nacht des Festes \\
  \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 
 
Ein Monat zählt acht Wochen. \\
  \vspace{8pt}

Der erste Monat \\
endet mit dem ersten Rastullahellah, \\
dem Tag des Fastens. \\
  \vspace{8pt}
 
Der zweite Monat \\ 
endet mit dem zweiten Rastullahellah, \\
dem Tag der Treue. \\
  \vspace{8pt}

Der dritte Montat \\
endet mit dem dritten Rastullahellah, \\
dem Tag der Blutrache.\\
  \vspace{8pt}

Der vierte Monat \\
endet mit dem vierten Rastullahellah, \\
dem Tag der Ruhe. \\
  \vspace{8pt}
  
Der fünfte Monat \\
endet mit dem fünften Rastullahellah, \\
dem Fest des Neuen Jahres. \\
  \vspace{\fill}
\newpage 

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*

\end{flushright}

\newpage

\afterpage{\blankpage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide more information about your document setup. For instance, which document class do you employ? Are you using the `tocloft` package? Do you use pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX to compile your document? How is "font A" related to the main document font? Is "font B" an OpenType font? Should "font B" be used at the same (nominal) font size as "font A"? If your document has a list of tables or a list of figures, should "font B" be used for the LoT and LoF as well?

Comment: There is an edit with an example: I want to use the font of the text for the text of the toc and the font of the numbers for the page numbers in the toc. In other words: I want to make use of two different fonts in the ToC. 

I am using lualatex.

Answer (score 0):

Using the example of your previous question [Page number troubles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/651002/161015)

The memoir package provides commands to configure the font of the page numbers used in the ToC, like

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapterformatpnum}{<font for chapters page numbers>}
```

[image: a]

[image: b]

Try this code.

```
 ...

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % ONLY for dummy text

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\color{red}\sffamily\large}% change page numbers font <<<<<<<<<< 
\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{\thepage}%

\renewcommand{\cftchapterformatpnum}{\color{red}\sffamily\bfseries\large}% change chapters page numbers font <<<<<<<<<

\renewcommand{\cftsectionformatpnum}{\color{red}\sffamily}% change sections page numbers font <<<<<<<<<
\begin{document}
    

\Bordertrue
    
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter

\chapter{ONE}
1. \kant[1-6]
\section{First section}
2. \kant[2]
\section{Second section}
3. \kant[3]
\chapter{TWO}
4. \kant[1-6]
    
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** without using chapters and with `\documentclass[a5paper,openany,article,12pt]{memoir}`

[image: c]

[image: e]

Try this code

```
...

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % ONLY for dummy text

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\color{red}\sffamily}% change page numbers font <<<<<<<<<<   
\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{\thepage}%

\renewcommand{\cftsectionformatpnum}{\color{red}\sffamily}% change sections page numbers font <<<<<<<<<
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}        

\Bordertrue
    
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter

\section{First section}
2. \kant[2]
\section{Second section}
3. \kant[3]
\section{Third section}
4. \kant[1-6]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so far. Only one problem: I am not making use of chapters, but of sections only. Using your code, the ToC stays empty. What should I change?

Comment: @Brayanokles Are you using `\documentclass[a5paper,openany,article,12pt]{memoir}`

Comment: This one:  \documentclass[12pt,openany,twoside,a5paper]{memoir}

Comment: @Brayanokles Please see the update of the answer. (remember to compile twice for the ToC to appear)

Comment: Problem is, the word "Table of contents" appears, but no contents. Not even after five compilations.

Comment: @Brayanokles Please post a complete compilable code from `\documentclass[12pt,openany,twoside,a5paper]{memoir}` to `\end{document}` that reproduces your issue.